# Helm | Jenkins Azure keyvault secrets are passing as masked(********),So it's throwing no value exception in helm command

Tags: azure, jenkins, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, azure-keyvault

I'm trying deploy the java microservices into azure kubernetes using helm charts, My application having few secret like DB username and passwords. I stored my secrets in azure keyvault. Using Azure Key vault plugin and service principal I'm trying to fetch the secrets. Test connection was successfully in the plugin and I can able print my secretes as I mentioned below. But while passing the secretes into helm commands i'm getting an following exception

> Error: failed parsing --set data: key "****" has no value

If I'm hardcoding the secretes, it's working.

My jenkins file looks like below

```
    *** Pipeline Code ***
pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
    DB-USERNAME = credentials('db-username')
    DB-PASSWORD = credentials('db-password')

  }
  stages {
    stage('Foo') {
      steps {
        echo DB-USERNAME
        echo DB-USERNAME.substring(0, DB-USERNAME.size() -1) // shows the right secret was loaded

sh 'helm upgrade --install $SERVICE $CHART_NAME --set $DB-USERNAME --set $DB-PASSWORD

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone please advise me on this

Reference :

https://linuxhelp4u.blogspot.com/2020/04/integrate-jenkins-with-azure-key-vault.html

https://plugins.jenkins.io/azure-keyvault/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `double quote` **sh** once

- if you are using `"double quotes"`, `$var` in sh `"... $var ..."` will be
  interpreted as **Jenkins** variable;
- if you are using 'single quotes', `$var` in sh `'... $var ...'` will be
  interpreted as **shell** variable.

Example

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
    DB-USERNAME = credentials('db-username')
    DB-PASSWORD = credentials('db-password')

  }
  stages {
    stage('Foo') {
      steps {
        echo DB-USERNAME
        echo DB-USERNAME.substring(0, DB-USERNAME.size() -1) // shows the right secret was loaded

sh "helm upgrade --install $SERVICE $CHART_NAME --set $DB-USERNAME --set $DB-PASSWORD"

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick turnaround. I tried with double quote sh as you suggested, But no luck still I'm facing the same issue

Comment: try adding `sh ''' commands '''` ref file https://github.com/harsh4870/basic-gitops-terraform-gcp-instance/blob/main/jenkinfile

Comment: Thanks. I tried the same. But still no luck,  I'm facing the same issue. I'm not sure I'm missing anything else, Still my secretes  are passing as ****

Comment: Found the root cause, problem is with helm --set key, after fixing the key. Above configuration works! Thank you very much!

Comment: Great glad to hear that.